# Send from view to controller with Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a question about send data from a view to a controller with ajax.
This is my View:

```
@model GDMfrontEnd.Models.DeliverableViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<h2>Uploaden!</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Deliverable", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <p><img src="~/Content/images/step1.png" />Selecteer jouw afbeeldingen</p>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Thumbnail)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Thumbnail, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Thumbnail)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Image, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoUrl)
        </div>

        <p><img src="~/Content/images/step2.png" />Informatie</p>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Projects)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Projects, "project_id", "project_name", Model.ProjectID))
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TagName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
             <input type="text" id="tags" />
        </div>

        <p>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
}
</div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            var object = {};
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Deliverable/Tags",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    object.tags = data;
                }
            });

            function split(val) {
                return val.split(/,\s*/);
            }
            function extractLast(term) {
                return split(term).pop();
            }
            $("#tags")
            // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
                .bind("keydown", function (event) {
                    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                })

                .autocomplete({
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                            object.tags, extractLast(request.term)));
                    },
                    focus: function () {
                        // prevent value inserted on focus
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        var terms = split(this.value);
                        // remove the current input
                        terms.pop();
                        // add the selected item
                        terms.push(ui.item.value);
                        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                        terms.push("");
                        this.value = terms.join(", ");

                        return false;
                    }
               });
            });
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Deliverable/AddTags",
                    data: terms,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function () {
                        alert('success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('failure');
                    }
                });
            });


    </script>
}
```

I have a html form with on the bottom a textbox where you can add tags to the textbox. (The tags are defined in the database)

The problem is that the ajax isn't doing anything. He doesn't even go in my action method.

Can anyone help me with this? I would like to send the array terms to an action method in my controller.

EDIT:

My Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddTags(List<string> data)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I just have a breakpoint at the beginning of the action to check if it reaches to the action but with no result..

Comment: could you show the signature of `AddTags` action, please?

Comment: Done! (See begin post)

Comment: Is the application on the root of the server that you're using? I mean, if you browse to `http://SERVER:PORT/` do you reach your app or is there something else, like `/dir/dir2/myApp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a HTTPPost attribute on your action, meaning that that action will only be mapped on post requests. In your ajax script you define by type Get, which means that the ajax request will be fired using a get request..

Remove that attribute or change the type of the request